# How to translate WordPress site

Tags: wordpress

I want to ask how can I translate my WordPress website. What I mean are the WP things like "continue reading" after some article is shown, "comments" on articles and all other things that users see on the website. I would like to translate that to my local language.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin:
https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/

for translate the string of themes, plugin and wordpress.

Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WPML](https://wpml.org/) - it is a paid plugin for translating content in multiple languages.

You can try other plugins like [GTranslate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gtranslate/), [LocoTranslate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) or [Weglot translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/weglot/).